# player.stopVideo, player.playVideo, etc. not working outside of event functions calls with youtube-api

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am trying to create a button that allows the user to click it and stop the embedded youtube video. However, whenever I try and call the player object itself to use the function player.playVideo() I get an error saying the function is not defined.

Player is globally defined and set when the Youtube API loads (just like the tutorial on their website). Function calls to playVideo work just fine when events trigger their usage, but using it outside of those simply do not work.

```
'''javascript
// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    isReady=true;
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    playVideo();
}

var done = false;
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
        setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
        done = true;
    }
}
function stopVideo() {
    player.pauseVideo();
}

function playVideo() {
    player.playVideo();
}

//The function that is run when the button is pressed, only in this case                      
 // stopVideo not work!
function togglePlay() {
    if(isPlaying) {
        stopVideo();
    } else {
        playVideo();
    }
}
'''
```

Expected: Youtube video plays
Actual: Error player.playVideo is not a function

Comment: I wonder if this has something to do with there being two functions called playVideo() - one in your script, and the other, I assume, in the YouTube API? Perhaps try using player.playVideo() in your onPlayerReady function, instead of calling another function to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am relatively certain that's not it, as I have tried getting rid of those functions altogether and simply calling player.playVideo and it still has the same issue.

Comment: @jgordley can you use jsfiddle for create a working sample of your code? of, by looking closely your code, I see you add `player.playVideo();` in the `onPlayerReady` function. use `event.target.playVideo();` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue. Something weird happens with even setting up buttons with onclick functions that use the player before the player is finished loading. To solve this, I moved all button declarations and functions inside the onPlayerReady(event) function and used event.target.play or event.target.pause and that worked perfectly. My advice is just to contain any declarations of buttons that use the youtube player functions inside of the onPlayerReady.